# Android get shared preferences from different files

Tags: android

in my android application i've got 4 differents shared preferences files, each one with his preferences.

To access and modify them i use a setting activity.

I've got some preferences which are not in this files but are in DefaultPreferences.

How can i read each shared preference from this files one by one?

I found this code but i can't get it works.

```
  SharedPreferences prefs_clima = getSharedPreferences("prefs_clima",MODE_PRIVATE);
            Map<String,?> keys = prefs_clima.getAll();
            for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
                Log.d("map values",entry.getKey() + ": " +
                        entry.getValue().toString());
            }
```

I always get zero preferences when reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this method and try to retrive the values

```
// retrive sharedpreference

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("prefs_clima", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 

//get values and assign it to variables
                String yourData = sharedPref.getString("keyName", "defaultValue");
//to get retrive int value
                int intValue = sharedPref.getInt("KeyName", 1);
```